# Per-article pseudonyms for blogging with option to link them later

Tags: web-apps, privacy, hosted, blog

I am interested in writing, but intend to write about a wide variety of topics, some of which are unconventional/politically incorrect enough that they may be detrimental to my professional reputation. And some of them are ideas that I would like to use my name for, and get credit if they gain reader traction. I am unable to judge right now which of them will be acceptable : At the start I will not associate my real identity with any of them.

Most blogging services allow pseudonymous accounts. But if I use them, then I cannot reveal my real name for the acceptable ones, without also revealing what else I write (potentially politically incorrect). Associating my real identity to a pseudonym is effectively irreversible on the internet.

(Anonymous) commenting facility for readers is a necessity for me. I also foresee a need to consolidate some essays by associating them with a single pseudonym, in order to let readers relate better to my other, interlinked essays.

Practically I foresee each essay getting a unique pseudonym, space for a brief bio for that pseuodonym, and a mechanism to update the bio. There also needs to be a large amount of existing content so that my essays don't form a significant fraction. That rules out hosting my own site.

The only existing site that allows low-overhead blogging and seems workable is http://write.as/ . It doesn't seem to have much content yet (Does it?), and I can't see a bio section.

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of many other solutions out there, but you should be able to do it with Write.as (*note*: I'm the creator), as it was built to help with this as much as possible.

We have over 7,000 published articles, and over 100 blogs created since we launched them last month, so your essays would make up a small fraction of all the writing out there.

We don't support commenting yet, but you can create multiple blogs under one account, and even move posts between them easily. Each blog is independent of the others (i.e. not publicly linked together), so you can have a pseudonymous blog or 20, and one for your real identity, but readers on one won't know the others exist.

Each also has a description at the top that could be used for a short bio — but if you had something else in mind, [let us know](https://write.as/contact) and we'll try to work that in, I like the idea.

Hope that helps.